# Is there any way to obtain the total number of results in a Facebook API search?

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to perform a search over the Facebook API and I'm aware that there is the limit parameter that limits the results (with a maximun of 5000) to a given number.
But it would be great to know what is the total number of results to show it to the user when she performs a search...is there any way?

I know how to get the length of the response, what I need to know is the TOTAL number of results (in the case of this number being greater than the limit).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow data mining operations, hence why they tend to limit or paginate results.  There's lots of money to be had in data mining, so Facebook is going to hold those cards close to their chest.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that requests returning multiple results might include a *count* field, such as:

```
{
    *id*: {
        "data": [
            {
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
    "count": 1500,
    "limit": 500,
    "offset": 0,
    "include_deleted": null
    "paging": {
             "next": ...
        },
    }
}
```

Though I just realized that some requests may not give the paging field. I'm working with ads and, for example, requesting all adgroups does not give a paging field when used with a campaign_id but does give a paging field when used with an account_id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe I wasn't explicit but what I'm doing is a /search over USER and/or over PAGE and neither of them returns count, just paging.next